# Not sure why I am getting a segmentation fault here

Tags: c, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

I know i can change the code to fix the error but I don't understand why I am getting a segmentation fault. All help is appreciated, thank you.

```
typedef struct nodes{
    int data;
    struct nodes *next;
} node;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    node *head = NULL;
    node *tmp = NULL;
    int i;

    head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp = head;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        tmp->data = i;
        tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    tmp = NULL;
    for(tmp=head; tmp->next != NULL; tmp = tmp->next){
        printf("%d\n", tmp->data);
    }

}
```

This is the output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get slightly cleaner code by building the list backwards. In other words, start by adding the last node to the list, and then insert additional nodes at the beginning of the list. The code looks like this:

```
node *head = NULL;
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
{
    node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->data = i;
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
}
```

Note that since `head` is initially `NULL`, the last node in the list will have its `next` pointer set to `NULL`. That's what was missing in your code.

Answer (score 3):

The `next` pointer of the last node is not set to `null`. Thus the condition `tmp->next != NULL` in the second `for`-loop will never be met. Indeed, you can see that some garbage number (`0`) is printed after the last number (`9`), before the seg fault occurs.

When you do this:

`tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(node));`

You should also add something like this:

`tmp->next->next = NULL;`

In this way, you initialize each node "safely", with the `next`-pointer set to `NULL`. All, but the last node, will get the correct value in the next iteration.

**EDIT** as pointed out by @Someprogrammerdude in the comment, you will end up with one extra node at the end, even if you do what is suggested above.
To fix that, you can change the creating-loop as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    tmp->data = i;
    if (i < 9) {
        tmp->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
    } else {
        tmp->next = NULL;
    }
    tmp = tmp->next;
}
```

Comment: Actually, the whole loop with its allocation is wrong. If the OP is trying to create a list of ten nodes, then the "last" (tenth) node will have a pointer to an eleventh node without initialized `data` or `next` members.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Good point, you are right, he will end up with the "garbage" node even with my proposed solution. I will edit the answer to point that out.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way of doing it instead of checking for the 'i<9' every iteration?

Comment: A simple `tmp->next= NULL;` after the `for`-loop suffices.